# Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense - Tensorflow IMU classifier

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am working on an example IMU classifier with Arduino nano 33 ble sense. I uploaded my own .csv data. but it gives a KeyError in the part below.I recorded all the data as aX, aY, aZ.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

filename = "sabit.csv"

df = pd.read_csv("/content/" + filename)

index = range(1, len(df['aX']) + 1)

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,10)

plt.plot(index, df['aX'], 'g.', label='x', linestyle='solid', marker=',')
plt.plot(index, df['aY'], 'b.', label='y', linestyle='solid', marker=',')
plt.plot(index, df['aZ'], 'r.', label='z', linestyle='solid', marker=',')
plt.title("Acceleration")
plt.xlabel("Sample #")
plt.ylabel("Acceleration (g)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.plot(index, df['jX'], 'g.', label='x', linestyle='solid', marker=',')
plt.plot(index, df['jY'], 'b.', label='y', linestyle='solid', marker=',')
plt.plot(index, df['jZ'], 'r.', label='z', linestyle='solid', marker=',')
plt.title("Gyroscope")
plt.xlabel("Sample #")
plt.ylabel("Gyroscope (deg/sec)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.plot(index, df['mX'], 'g.', label='x', linestyle='solid', marker=',')
plt.plot(index, df['mY'], 'b.', label='y', linestyle='solid', marker=',')
plt.plot(index, df['mZ'], 'r.', label='z', linestyle='solid', marker=',')
plt.title("Magnetometer")
plt.xlabel("Sample #")
plt.ylabel("Magnetometer (G)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

error;

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
  

KeyError: 'aX'
```

Why does this problem occur?

Comment: This means that the column `aX` was not found in your df,  to be sure of this it is possible to evaluate a condition like `if 'aX 'in df: return True else return False`

Comment: Thank you. I saw the problem and I fix it. problem was my csv file.